# WebDriverIO - Delete Native App storage and cache for Android and iOS using Appium

Tags: typescript, appium, wdio

We are using WDIO to automate Android and iOS tests. Is there a way to delete the application storage and cache.

The method like resetApp() does not seem to be available.

The tech stack is Typescript, Appium and WDIO